# WPF: Sort a list box

Tags: wpf, sorting, listbox

How do I sort a `ListBox` by two fields? (In this case the `ApplicationName` and `InstanceName` properties of my model class.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your data source. Here are a couple of ways....

using linq on lisbox data source

[from 101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756.aspx#thenBySimple):

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
var sortedDigits =
        from d in digits
        orderby d.Length, d
        select d;
```

use a CollectionView for your listbox and add a [SortDescription](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/)

```
ICollectionView myDataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myData);

using (myDataView.DeferRefresh()) // we use the DeferRefresh so that we refresh only once
{
   myDataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
   if (SortById)
      myDataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ApplicationName", direction));
   if (SortByName)
         myDataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("InstanceName", direction));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to add both fields into the listbox items [SortDescriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.sortdescription.aspx) collection, smth like this:

```
listBox1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ApplicatonName", ListSortDirection.Descending));
listBox1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("InstanceName", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

above code should sort the listbox items in the descending order by fileds ApplicatonName and InstanceName

hope this helps, regards