# Sorting ObservableCollection by String

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Observable Collection and an item of the collection has a tag (string) and a isChecked (boolean).

The User can select a tag to sort the list e.g. "event" and/or set the IsChecked.

The Ordering priority should work like this:
1) isChecked == true
2) tag equals the item tag
3) rest of the items sorted alphabetically by tag

I show the ObservableCollection in a ListBox through xaml.
Any idea how this can be achieved?

```
EDIT: providing example for clarification:
item0: tag = "apple", isChecked = false;
item1: tag = "apple", isChecked = true;
item2: tag = "pineapple", isChecked = false;
item3: tag = "coconut", isChecked = true;
item4: tag = "cherry", isChecked = false;

string is: "cherry"
outcome: item1, item3, item4, item0, item2
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  The first Google result for "sort wpf listbox" is a question on this very site...

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: Sort a list box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136827/wpf-sort-a-list-box)

Comment: I do not only sort by field  but on a string :/ (found that solution, too. Would work for 1 and 3 but not for 2)
see example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to retrieve your conditions, I did the below.

```
 // Retrieve an IQueryable for the colleciton with your specified conditions
 var query = from c in collection
             orderby c.IsChecked descending, c.Tag.Equals("cherry") descending, c.obsTag
             select c;

 // Clear the collection
 collection = new ObservableCollection<myCollectionObject>();
 // Replace the collection with your IQueryable results
 foreach(myCollectionObject obj in query) {
      collection.Add(obj);
 }
```

If you want it all in one line:

```
 collection = new ObservableCollection<obsCol>(from c in collection 
              orderby c.obsCheck descending, c.obsTag.Equals("cherry") descending, c.obsTag 
 select c);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be separated from the implementation not only of the UI but of the model too, you have to use [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)

The concrete example of how to sort the list of objects via some custom Comprarer, can be found here:

[WPF: ListCollectionView for sorting, filtering and grouping](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/08/31/wpf-listcollectionview-for-sorting-filtering-and-grouping.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but how to map the sorting requirements on a ViewSource?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: you have a set of objects, you define a comparer, you run that comparer that contains specific sortig rules, over view source. The basic steps. I proveded a link to concrete implementation for OP.

Comment: But #2 is tag equals the item tag so need to pass a value to icomparer and the interface does not seem to support that.

Comment: On #2 I understand it like a set of fields that can define different sorting keys. In this way you can have a colleciton of "sorting keys", and on selection of one of them run appropriate comparer.

Answer (score 0):

That #2 is a little trickier.

For that you may need to have another Public Enumerable in code behind that builds that up in two steps.

OP please clarify what #2 is before I go down this path.

2 Tag equals the tag

3 Alphabetically by tag

Not clear at all.  Three reference to tag.

Based on your comment need top build up the List in two sets
The problem statement does not reflect the comment.
You cannot expect people to read comments.

IsChecked = True and Tag = 'match'

then append

IsChecked = false or Tag != 'match' order by tag

Sorry I don't have time for the LINQ right now and to be honest you have not shown much effort on a good problem statement.

Comment: 2) A string varibale is compared to the tag on each item. If both are the same. These items are listed first.
3) All other items that don't fit into 1) and 2) are sorted by their tag alphabetically.  

e.g. ; item0: tag = "apple"; item1: tag = "hour"; item2: tag = "event"...string variable = "event"...
Final order:  item2, item0 ,item1