# How to reorder CollectionViewSource like this?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, collectionviewsource

I just got some data like this

```
{
    "ID":2,
    "NOTAMRec":"C16-0001",
    "DeliverDate":"310827",
    "BeginDate":"1601010130",
    "ExpireDate":"1606070630",
    "Priority":"GG",
    "ItemA":"LOL",
    "OriginalNotamID":2,
    "SelectedNotamColor":null
},
{
    "ID":8,
    "NOTAMRec":"C16-0004",
    "DeliverDate":"230705",
    "BeginDate":"1602231505",
    "ExpireDate":"1606312359 EST",
    "Priority":"GG",
    "ItemA":"LOVEU",
    "OriginalNotamID":8,
    "SelectedNotamColor":null
},
{
    "ID":9,
    "NOTAMRec":"C16-0005",
    "DeliverDate":"240703",
    "BeginDate":"1602241502",
    "ExpireDate":"1606312359 EST",
    "Priority":"GG",
    "ItemA":"LOVEU",
    "OriginalNotamID":9,
    "SelectedNotamColor":null
}
```

**My Model**

```
public Class MyModel 
{
  public long ID {get;set;}
  public string NOTAMRec {get;set;}
  public string ItemA {get;set;}
}
```

And add this into an ObservableCollection.

Then `new CollectionViewSource().Source = theObservableCollection`

**Problem** - I wanted to sort my ViewSource in this order and display it in a DataGridView.

No matter how many MyModels I add into this collection, Models whose **`ItemA` equals to "`LOVEU`"** will always in the **top of this list**.

so when I display this list to my user, they will always see the `MyModels` with `LOVEU` in the first place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
 var order = yourCollection.OrderByDescending(y => y.ItemA.IndexOf("LOVEU"));
```

> This will sort based on the property Name here is its `Name` and it will sort by ascending by default

**Edit:**
Please see the full code over here [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jrfXOy)

Comment: THANKS  , I tried this worked but the SortDescription will not satisfy my needs, which is to put Items with "LOVEU" always on the top list

Comment: You dont need `collection source` for this , just directly bind the `order`  the collection to you control. It will be ordered as you see. Please see the `dotnetfiddle` so will get a idea

Answer (score 0):

Cagaya Coper  Try this

```
   var query = from c in theObservableCollection
                 orderby  c.ItemA.Equals("LOVEU") descending , c.ID
                 select c; 
new CollectionViewSource().Source = query
```

[Sorting ObservableCollection by String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822306/sorting-observablecollection-by-string)

Comment: Hai when i try ruining this in my console `LOVEU` has been in sorted as last.

Comment: Thanks, but this change can not display in my Datagridview as I clicked a button Named Sort.

Comment: HI , Eldho I fixed, I have missed descending, any way, if you wanna , try again

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion to you is ,use event sort and modify the order.

```
 grid.DataContext = ObservableCollection.OrderByDescending(y => y.ItemA.IndexOf("LOVEU")); 

 private void grid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataContext));
        if (e.Column != null && e.Column.CanUserSort == true && e.Column.Header.ToString() != "ItemA")
        {
            var dgSender = (DataGrid)sender;
            var cView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgSender.ItemsSource);

            cView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            cView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ItemA", ListSortDirection.Descending));

            if (e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {   
                e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                cView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(e.Column.Header.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Descending));
            }
            else
            {   
                e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                cView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(e.Column.Header.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```